# Avast detects PHP built in web server as a virus

Tags: windows, windows-10, php, anti-virus, xampp

I'm using Avast free version, Windows 10 64 bit and XAMPP. Every time I run PHP built in web server, Avast detects it as a virus

```
php -S localhost:8000 file.php
```

I added the files as exception, that didn't change anything, maybe I should add `php.exe` or the entire XAMPP folder?

I filed a false positive to Avast, I also reported the bug to XAMPP, just in case it's a XAMPP problem.

Comment: What virus does it detect as, out of interest?

Comment: @bertieb it detects it as idp generic virus

Answer (score 2):

Avast team solved the issue, it wasn't related to XAMPP, it was related I believe to the behavior of the browsers, that's my understanding of what say said in their email.

Maybe if you opened `localhost:port` and have a web server running and if you opened it from terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click on the link, that could be detected as a malware, as far as I understand.

In any case, now they cleared that from their malware database.

Comment: After retesting, it seems that Avast didn't fix it yet, when they fix it for good, I'll remove this comment

Comment: I'm still getting this issue when I run a .php script from the debugger in VSCode, originally it was just deleting the PHP file, then I restarted my machine, and it popped up with a message saying that it had detected IDP.Generic. - Also, after deleting the PHP file (with no warning) I couldn't see anywhere to recover it.. very annoying